# Sentence ending じょ

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, sentence-final-particles

> 「この寒いのによく山へなんて行ったねェ。**そんで、いたの**？」
>   You went to places like the mountains often in these cold days, right? And, there was...?
>   「アハハー、**いたじょいたじょーっ**。」

Firstly, how should I understand そんで、いたの? Is it like an incomplete question inviting the listener to finish the sentence? e.g.

> So you went to the zoo and you saw...?
>   That's right. I saw an elephant.

Secondly, what is the meaning of the じょ/じょー in the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

そんで、いたの？ (= それで、いたの？) means "And, was (it) there?" "And, did you see/find (it) there?" そんで is a colloquial, collapsed way of pronouncing それで. The subject for the verb いた(居た) is left out.

いたじょいたじょ (= いたぞいたぞ) literally means "(It) was there, (it) was there." This is how 山田くん in anime ちびまる子ちゃん usually talks (e.g. 「～だじょー。」「～したじょー。」 ). I think young children tend to pronounce the sentence-final particle ～ぞ as ～じょ, though it could be a regional dialect.

> "(I'm surprised that) You managed to go to the mountains in such a cold day. And, was it there? / And, did you find it there?"
>   "Ahaha, yes, it was there! / yes, I found it there!"

---

By the way, the よく means "manage to (do something difficult)", not "often." Eg:

> - 君、**よく**行ったね。
>     What a surprise you managed to go.
> - **よく**まあ無事に帰ってこられましたね。
>     How lucky you got back safe and sound!

Answer (score 1):

Another translation could be:

> It's so cold, and yet you're able to go to places like mountains. So, did you?

The それで、いたの？ is like,  "so, were you there?" or "so, did you go?" if the dialect drops the small つ.

---

According to this [question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1459356054): 「じょ」 comes from the Wakayama-dialect and is used in place of the sentence final 「よ」.

The 「いたじょ」is like 「いたよ」, "I was there" or "I went there" if the dialect drops the small つ.

Comment: Interesting that this じょ is a definite dialect.  I initially interpreted it as the speaker using the particle ぞ, but they were speaking with a stuffy nose.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Hahahaha  that could be right too, I have no idea the correct answer :P

Comment: I didn't know じょ is also used in Wakayama. I've believed it's a typical 阿波弁 word :)

Comment: @naruto Neither did I until I searched it up :P.

Comment: @naruto I actually didnt know it was in either until I searched it up